# Deleting dynamic variable pointed to by node in linked list

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment for an intermediate programming class. We're creating a Cluster class, where each Cluster object contains objects from a Point class. The `points` member of a Cluster object points to the head node of a linked list of LNode objects, and each LNode points to a Point object:

```
namespace Clustering {

    typedef Point *PointPtr;
    typedef struct LNode *LNodePtr;

    struct LNode {
        PointPtr p;
        LNodePtr next;
    };

    class Cluster {

    private:
        int size;
        LNodePtr points;  // points to head LNode
```

My problem has cropped up when I try to overload the assignment operator to handle expressions like Cluster1 = Cluster2. To prevent a memory leak, I want to delete the entire linked list of LNode-s that Cluster1 points to, as well as each Point that each LNode points to. This seems straightforward enough:

```
// Overload assignment operator
Cluster& Cluster::operator =(const Cluster& otherCluster) {

    // checks for equality
    if (this == &otherCluster)
        return *this;

    size = otherCluster.size;

    // delete old nodes
    if (points != nullptr) {
        LNodePtr discard = points;
        points = nullptr;
        LNodePtr advance = discard->next;
        do {
            cout << "flag " << *(discard->p) << endl;
            delete discard->p;  // this line should delete the Point
            delete discard;
            discard = advance;
            if (advance != nullptr)
                advance = advance->next;
        } while (discard != nullptr);
    }
```

However, my code only works without the `delete discard->p;` line. When I include that line, I get strange behavior. Sometimes the program will delete the Point for every LNode until the last LNode, where the line causes the program to crash. I placed an output flag before the `delete` line to confirm that the Point I want to delete still exists (it does). At other times, the `delete` line  causes other parts of my program to fail.

I would appreciate any help anyone could give. I tried to search for other questions asking about this problem, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Well, I would recommend stepping through your code with the debugger first.

Comment: I did do that. The program crashes at the delete line without explanation.

Comment: That usually happens if you're trying to delete an already deleted or uninitialised pointer.

Comment: If the pointer had already been deleted, would I be able to correctly output the Point object? I ran a short test program where I created a Point with two pointers pointing to it. I then deleted one of the pointers and tried to output the Point through the other pointer. The output was incorrect.

Comment: @Lawrence303  πάντα ῥεῖ is right.  The fact that you manage to display the detroyed object doesn't mean that it was not destroyed (depends on destructor, on library, on reuse or not of teh memory by a subsequent allocation).  Can you show us how you allocated the points ?  Can you confirm that you didn't allocate an array of points ?

Comment: Do you have also copy constructor and destructor defined? Can you show the entire code of all three?

Comment: Are you sure that `this` and `otherCluster` don't share structure (i.e. the same `Point` instances)? Could you please show how the `Cluster`s in question were constructed?

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. Your suggestions helped me to find the problem. It turned out that I was double-deleting the pointer. I feel a little sheepish now because it should have been obvious.